# Java 2D Graphics rotating objects keeping original coords system?

Tags: java, rotation, coordinates

I've already searched this topic everywhere on the Internet, but nothing.

I'm programming with JAVA and I'm painting in a JPanel some shapes like yellow stars with a sort of spaceship in the center of the screen. My purpose is to make the entire scene, apart from the spaceship which remains stationary at the center, rotate around the center (and of course around the spaceship) when I press a certain button.

Now, when I rotate the stars I make them rotate around the center point wich changes as the spaceship moves, but when I do a rotation, the coordinates system changes and the ship moves diagonally, while I want to rotate the scene keeping possible to move the spaceship vertically and horizontally.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    // RIEMPIMENTO SFONDO
    g2.setColor(new Color(10, 10, 10));
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, 1366, 768);

    // DEBUGGER
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.drawString("|" + posx + "|" + posy + "|   " + scale, 1250, 758);

    // TRASFORMAZIONE NAVICELLA
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.translate(683, 384);
    at.scale(scale, scale);
    g2.setTransform(at);
    AffineTransform backup = g2.getTransform();

    // DISEGNO NAVICELLA
    g2.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    int[] xp = {0, -25, -25, 0, 25, 25};
    int[] yp = {-25, 0, 25, 0, 25, 0};
    g2.drawPolygon(xp, yp, 6);

    // TRASFORMAZIONE SPAZIO
    at.translate(posx, posy);
    at.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotation), -posx, -posy);
    g2.setTransform(at);

    // DISEGNO SPAZIO
    STAR(g2, 300 + posx, 100 + posy, 200, 200, Color.YELLOW);
    STAR(g2, -100 + posx, -200 + posy, 200, 200, Color.YELLOW);

    g2.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Rotate the *ship* when you rotate the *camera*, that should keep it stationary relative to the camera... I think that's what you're asking for anyway.

Comment: In fact the ship remains stationary, the only things that move are the objects around but when I move the spaceship, it moves through the rotated coords. For exemple, if I rotate 90 degrees the scene, the ship doesn't move towards the top screen if I press W, but it moves through the Y coordinate because I've rotated the scene.